# Cannot resolve method 'select' error message at QueryDSL.select in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, querydsl

I am trying to select after grouping using QueryDSL. I created a constructor like this:

```
 @QueryProjection
    public RankingListGetRes(String nickName, String department, String totalStudyTime) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
        this.department = department;
        this.totalStudyTime = totalStudyTime;
    }
```

I am trying to create an object using the new constructor using the @QueryProjection annotation.
However, the message **Cannot resolve method 'select(*.api.response.RankingListGetRes)'** appears
under the new constructor  **new RankingListGetRes(qStudyTime.user.nickname.toString(), qStudyTime.user.department.name.toString(), qStudyTime.time.sum().toString())**

How can I solve this? Below this is my code.

```
    public PageImpl<RankingListGetRes> getTotalStudyTimesByUserPaging(Pageable pageable) {
        QStudyTime qStudyTime = QStudyTime.studyTime;

        JPQLQuery<RankingListGetRes> query = jpaQueryFactory.select(new RankingListGetRes(qStudyTime.user.nickname.toString(), qStudyTime.user.department.name.toString(), qStudyTime.time.sum().toString()))
                .from(qStudyTime)
                .groupBy(qStudyTime.user);

        long totalCount = query.fetchCount(); // 2)
        List<RankingListGetRes> results = Objects.requireNonNull(getQuerydsl()).applyPagination(pageable, query).fetch();  // 3)
        return new PageImpl<>(results, pageable, totalCount);  // 4)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Projections.constructor(RankingListGetRes.class, qStudyTime.user.nickname.toString(), qStudyTime.user.department.name.toString(), qStudyTime.time.sum().toString())
```

or you need to annotate your DTO as this:

```
class CustomerDTO {

  @QueryProjection
  public CustomerDTO(long id, String name) {
     ...
  }

}
```

to call it like this:

```
select(new QCustomerDTO(customer.id, customer.name))
```

Source: [querydsl.com](https://querydsl.com)